# How to speed up AutoComplete in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete

I am having some problem with the following code and need help in getting it work for URIs strings.

It works when I type `a`, `b`,... I know my `List<URI>` is collecting the addresses, but AutoComplete does not work on the addresses.
I did debug the code and `ProcessFile()` seems to work fine and matches URIs and collects them. I saw seven address in there at one point.

But `totalUris` instance in the `col.Add()` statement is empty. I do not know why `totalUris` list does not get populated. The whole thing runs kind of slow also. I did see a similar functionality for WPF, and they used keywords.

I wonder if I have to do this here also and how would that work. That is any primer code to get me started is greatly appreciated.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void addItems(AutoCompleteStringCollection col)
        {
            string favorites = @"C:\Users\zohal\Favorites";
            List<Uri> totalUris = new List<Uri>();
            if (File.Exists(favorites))
            {
                // This path is a file
                ProcessFile(favorites, out totalUris);
                col.Add(totalUris.ToString());
            }
            else if (Directory.Exists(favorites))
            {
                // This path is a directory
                ProcessDirectory(favorites,col);
                col.Add(totalUris.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No file or directory to process");
            }

            col.Add(totalUris.ToString());
            col.Add("Abel");
            col.Add("Bing");
            col.Add("Catherine");
            col.Add("Varghese");
            col.Add("John");
            col.Add("Kerry");
        }
        public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory, AutoCompleteStringCollection col)
        {
            List<Uri> favoriteUrisInCurrentDirectory = new List<Uri>();
            // Process the list of files found in the directory.
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                //if (fileName == "desktop.ini") ???
                //cumulativeUris.AddRange(favoriteUrisInCurrentDirectory = ProcessFile(fileName));
                ProcessFile(fileName, out favoriteUrisInCurrentDirectory);
            // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
            string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
            foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
                ProcessDirectory(subdirectory,col);
        }
        // Insert logic for processing found files here.
        public static void ProcessFile(string theFile, out List<Uri> totalUris)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", theFile);
            // Add the file to the list of internet shortcut files 
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(theFile);
            System.String line;
            List<Uri> favoriteUris = new List<Uri>();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Go through the file, and match any URIs, and add them to a list
                Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*");
                //Regex r = new Regex (@"http(s) ?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$");
                //Regex r = new Regex(@"http(s) ?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$");
                //Regex r = new Regex(@"(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
                // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
                Match m = r.Match(line);
                Uri currentUri;

                while (m.Success)
                {
                    currentUri = new Uri(m.ToString());
                    favoriteUris.Add(currentUri);
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
            }
            totalUris = favoriteUris;
        }

        private void personalUrisTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personalUrisTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            personalUrisTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            addItems(DataCollection);
            personalUrisTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `totalUris` is a `List<Uri>`. What does this code produce? => `col.Add(totalUris.ToString());`. -- You are rebuilding the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` of your TextBox in its  `TextChanged` event hanlder. Each time the text changes. Is there a reason why those methods are `static`?

Comment: @jim- Yup it needs updating; that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a directory

> @"C:\Users\zohal\Favorites"

so the method `ProcessDirectory` will be called and then will iterate through all files of the directory. The problem is that you method `ProcessFile` uses **out** keyword which means the list will get cleared and then filled with the Uris in that file. hence, when the last file is called and if it is empty, the list will be empty.

Also The `ProcessDirectory` method itself does not return anything neither makes any change on the inputs. so try this:

use **ref** keyword instead of out here:

```
public static void ProcessFile(string theFile, ref List<Uri> totalUris)
{
    //.... rest of the code
    totalUris.AddRange(favoriteUris);
}
```

also make changes to the `ProcessDirectory` Method:

```
public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory, ref List<Uri> totalUris)
{
    // **avoid reconstructing the list:** List<Uri> favoriteUrisInCurrentDirectory = new List<Uri>();
    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        ProcessFile(fileName, ref totalUris);

    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
    foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory, ref totalUris);
}
```

Hope it Helps.